# About if else statement

Tags: php, if-statement, time

here is the code!

code1 :

```
if(false) {
    //1000 lines of code
}
else {
    //1 line of code
}
```

code2 :

```
if(false) {
    //1 line of code
}
else {
    //1 line of code
}
```

what will be the process time of above two codes? Also please try to explain...

Comment: Ignoring variation in parsing: basically the same for processing, assuming that the `1 line of code` is the same.... execute the evaluation for the if, then execute that 1 line of code... of course, if those 1 lines of code are different, one may take longer to evaluate than the other

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok ok it's very good question about performance.

Short answer: they will run in the same speed. Why

the compiler when it complies your code it will translate it to mechine language which is bunch of low level processor commands in RAM

In the `if` with one line if the condition is false the complier will ask the processor to jump 1 line this will increase the program counter with one to ignore the `if` block and execute the else block instead. look the overhead is just one command to increase the program counter.

`program counter` is register that saves which line you are executing

and in the `if` with 1000 line it will be simply the same just increase the program counter with 1000 to jump the `if` block to execute the `else` block. One Operation the overhead is the same.

thats it even with `else` is the same if condition true `if` block will executed then jump the `else` block.